# How to connect Redis and Couchbase in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, couchbase

How can I connect redis and couchbase to my spring application.
I get this error `Parameter 0 of method couchbaseMappingContext in org.springframework.data.couchbase.config.AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found: - couchbaseCustomConversions: defined by method 'customConversions' in class path resource [{classPath}/chat/config/CouchbaseConfiguration.class] - redisCustomConversions: defined in null`
I only need redis to 'look' at one package and the other ones need to be connected with only couchbase.

Redis config

```
  @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter =
                new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Long, ?> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<Long, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        // Add some specific configuration here. Key serializers, etc.
        return template;
    }
```

Couchbase config

```
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {


    @Value("${spring.data.couchbase.bucket-name}")
    private String bucketName;
    
    @Value("${spring.couchbase.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.couchbase.password}")
    private String password;
    
    @Value("${spring.couchbase.connection-string}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Override
    public String getConnectionString() {

        return this.connectionString;
    }


    @Override
    public String getUserName() {

        return this.username;
    }


    @Override
    public String getPassword() {

        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBucketName() {
          
        return this.bucketName;
    }

}
```

and when I first start my app in terminal there is this info : Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface

Comment: I can't help you, but I am really curious to understand the "why"

Comment: @MatthewGroves I think that this resolved the problem I added 

`@Override
 @Bean(value = "customConversions")
 public CustomConversions customConversions() {
  return super.customConversions();
 }`

in CouchbaseConfig and in RedisConfig 

`
 @Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, ?> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {"......"} `

And it worked

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked. Still interested in knowing more about your use case and why you're using a combination of redis+couchbase

Comment: @MatthewGroves I am sorry, but the info is confidential I think. I'm not doing it for my personal project.

Comment: No problem. Just seems odd to me, since Couchbase already has a built in cache that you would use another cache on top of it. But if there IS such a use case where it makes sense, I'd love to learn more about it. Discussing the same thing in a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66439034/multiple-customconversions-beans-in-application-while-using-couchbase-and-redis (maybe a teammate of yours?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve the ambiguity in taking the customConversions bean, we could tell the couchbase configuration class how to create the customConversions bean. Adding the below code to the class which extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration should solve the issue

```
@Bean
  public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        return super.customConversions();
  }
```

Comment: error: 

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseCustomConversions' defined in class path resource [com/company/finance/team/config/CouchbaseConfig.class]: No matching factory method found on class [com.company.finance.team.config.CouchbaseConfig]: factory bean 'couchbaseConfig'; factory method 'customConversions()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.`